# How to get around updateMany (not working) in mongoose, nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I would like to update the author name of a post (esc. old posts by that user) anytime that user updates his profile name.

My code looks like this,

```
router('/:id', async (req, res) {
    if (req.body._id == req.params.id) {
        try {
            const user = await User.find(req.params.id):
                let oldfirstName = user.firstname;
            let oldlastName = user.lastname;

            const author = oldfirstName + ' ' + oldlastName;

            const postsByUser = await Post.find({ author: author }); // gets posts by same user

            const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
                {
                    $set: {
                        firstname: req.body.firstname,
                        lastname: req.body.lastname,
                    }
                }
            });
            let updatedAuthor = updatedUser.firstname + ' ' + updatedUser.lastname;
            await postsByUser.updateMany({}, { author: updatedAuthor });
        });
    res.status(200).json();
        } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong please?

I am building a blog. Users full name equals the displayed author name. I tried updating the author's name on old posts anytime there is an update in user's firstname or lastname on profile. I could update user's profile, but the new update does not apply to old posts by that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line seems off to me:

`await postsByUser.updateMany({}, {author: updatedAuthor});`

`postsByUser` is not a Model.

You likely just want to issue an update like this:
`await Post.updateMany({author: author}, {$set: {author: updatedAuthor}})`
Which is essentially saying "update all posts where author is the "old" author name, and set it to the new author name".

Comment: If only i can upvote multiple times. This solves it exactly

Comment: Thanks @mjosh - if you wouldn't mind accepting the answer as well, that shows other users that find this post that it solved your problem.